# How to parse data from KML to shapefile with ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, modelbuilder, kml, arcgis-10.2

In ModelBuilder of ArcGIS 10.2 does there exist a method or routine for parsing data from a KML file and "print" this data in a shapefile or convert this data a to shapefile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **[KML to Layer (Conversion)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00120000004w000000)** tool which:

> Converts a KML or KMZ file into feature classes and a layer file. The
>   layer file maintains the symbology found within the original KML or
>   KMZ file.

You can then use the **[Feature Class to Feature Class (Conversion)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000020000000)** tool to convert the resultant geodatabase feature class(es) to shapefile(s).

You can use these two tools to build your model.

Comment: hello, thanks for this method involves knowing the file name, which is not used in a model, and if you want to acquire more information from a folder